# Object persistence without database mapping

Tags: java, jpa, orm, nosql

I am looking for an advice on persisting Java objects without the need for database mapping. In simple (and silly) words I want to have JPA, but not be bothered by details of database structure: tables, columns, keys. Ideally what I would like to achieve is just defining Java classes, instantiating objects and persisting/retrieving these objects and their associations without any need for repeating entities/properties information anywhere else. I know that there are various kinds of NOSQL databases, document databases, key-value storages and so on, but I have close-to-zero experience with anything other than flavors of RDBMSes and by simply reading descriptions and manuals of Cassandra, BerkeleyDB, MongoDB etc I am even unable to judge whether they support my use cases or not ;( So here are my requirements:

- I am going to use Java programming language, so it would be nice if
  there were some JARs with API to access database
- My main goal is to avoid the need of defining an object-to-table mapping, as I see it superfluous and I consider the type definition as the only necessary source of metadata for persistence. Anything more is too much, maybe except some properties for fine-tuning (converters, transient fields, etc.) So if there is some JPA/RDBMS based solution that would let me completely avoid touching database schema, I take it.
- Object graphs in my application are going to have many relationships, there is going to be no logical top-level object which aggregates other sub-objects as fully contained properties. On the contrary, my model contains quite a few top level classes, which will be referenced more or less directly by other types with one-to-many and many-to-many associations. For this reason I *guess* that semi-structural, document-based and JSON-based storage (CouchDB, MongoDB) won't suit my needs, as I could not find the way of easily expressing relationships between objects (i.e. documents) other than aggregation. Or I am just wrong.
- Number of persisted objects is going to be 'average', i.e. there is no need for particular massive scalability, big-data functionalities etc. I'd estimate a number of objects as hundreds of thousands.
- I need the storage to be transactional, with commit on success/rollback on error mechanisms or equivalent.
- Schema evolution should not require any operations on underlying storage schema. So when my model changes, all I want to do is retrieve object, modify/recalculate properties, and store modified object. No need to change any tables, columns, etc.
- I would need to execute some queries based on object properties. Not really complicated ones, with just regular relational operators, but possibly with joins ( `FROM Book b WHERE b.price < :allowedPrice AND b.author=:author`).
- As it is going to be used in my hobby, eventually-to-become-commercial, project, Id'd like it to be free for commercial use (ideally), or with some non-restrictive licensing for as long as it stays an after-hours thing (and this might be *ages*).

Actually from what I have read, it seems that some object database would be the best choice for me, for example DB4O or ObjectDB. Unfortunately, DB4O is dead, and license for ObjectDB seems to be a bit too demanding for me. Maybe there are some possibilities I am not aware of to fulfill above requirements with something else, some NoSQL solution or some set of tools on top of 'regular' RDBMS.

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

Comment: looks like you need `Hibernate`. it will create you tables just like your classes and there is no need to define much besides telling hibernate that a class should be mapped at all

Comment: I am yet to see a project where `hbm2ddl.auto=update` causes no grief. In a long run, it hardly ever proves to be a good idea.

Comment: Well, that is something you will have to deal in every case. I can't imagine any tool which has no need to update the database once you make changes to your classes (unless you configure a specific name to keep)

Comment: impossible to make JPA project, totally without DB knowledge. Correct answer is "is possible with limited DB engeenering?"

Comment: SQL or NoSQL has not single answer. NoSQL acronym is umbrella over many totally different things.

Comment: Eclipselink JPA implementation seems have more (?) options for NoSQL. All are extensions (non standard). Difference between relational, ant not relational DB are deep. Transactionality totally differ

Comment: JDX ORM can meet most of your needs, some partially though. The library comes in a lightweight JAR with simple APIs. Mapping specification is minimal; non-intrusive; most of the default mapping is derived automatically; primary key attributes for each model class have to be specified; minimal specification for relationships needed. Schema is created automatically but changing the model would require schema changes if new persistent fields are added. Flexible queries including path-expression support. Free eval version; developer license fee, runtime free. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDX.

Comment: @Jacek Cz "impossible to make JPA project, totally without DB knowledge" - if you meant to say you absolutely need to specify *some* properties of the database schema when modelling the mapping, then I beg to differ. JPA fully follows convention over configuration in this regard

Comment: relational database and mapping into obejct concept of Java has known difficulties, broad discussed. Impossible to ignore part of this knowledge

Comment: @crizzis while what you say is pretty much right when my app needs to work with db X, I found it hard to create working JPA mapping in a way, that 1) it would contain no information about DB schema and 2) would allow replacing one JPA provider with another, or one RDBMS driver with another. Maybe I haven't tried hard enough, but such db-agnostic mapping failed on some naming details, like identifier quoting, case-sensitivity of names, generated names for constraints, referencing ID generators... If I specified DB elements explicitly in mapping, it usually worked.

Comment: .... All I really want is to work with objects, and not database, and that's why I wonder whether I can totally get rid of RDBMS for object persistence, or at least abstract it far enough to forget about DB details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to focus mainly on object DB solutions, and unfortunately I could not find many of them. I evaluated ObjectDB and I have to admit that it's the best persistence solution I happened to work with.

Pros:

- It supports both JPA and JDO APIs, so using OBjectDB is just as easy as using any ORM-based solution. If you know JPA or JDO, you have no entry cost for starting with ObjectDB. If you stick to some really basic guidelines, you can switch between ObjectDB and ORM almost at will, just by changing connection string and deployed JARs.
- ObjectDB does what almost none of persistence libraries does: it let's you focus on persistence task without any disturbances and inconveniences caused the underlying storage. You define your model just once, as entity classes, and you do not need to repeat yourself and handle any tables, columns, ORMs (`orm.xml`, be gone!), DB schema evolution, moving data between column on schema updates...
- ObjectDB has more relaxed requirements than JPA ORM. You can persist objects of almost any type (GUIDs, new Date and Time API!), you need fewer annotations (for example, relationship annotations, i.e. `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany` and others) are not required. However you still need them if you need source compatibility between ObjectDB and JPA ORM.

Cons:

- It's a commercial product, and as such it requires you to get a license. It's possible to use ObjectDB for free (commercially or not), but only for up to 10 entity classes. Sometimes it might be possible to get free, unlimited license for evaluation purposes - or at least there used to be such information on ObjectDB page, but I do not know if it's possible now - I did not ask.
- While JPA seems to be almost fully supported, static metamodel API is not. There is no static metamodel generator, and even when you'd create it by hand, criteria API methods with metamodel arguments throw *Not Supported* exception. It might be an obstacle if you'd plan to switch from existing solution (for example, Hibernate) to ObjectDB. Hopefully support for static metamodel will be added some time in the future.

For me, ObjectDB seems to be *exactly* what I need, and I will evaluate it further to check other aspects, as performance, conformance to more obscure corners of JPA and possibility of easy replacement with ORM when needed, schema evolution, etc.